# salesforce - update error - Artifact

Tags: salesforce

I am getting this everytime I open eclipse

Artifact not found: http://developer.force.com/content.jar.

I have uninstalled Force.com plugin from eclipse.

Any idear?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the Force.com perspective is still lingering (Eclipse seems to maintain a list of perspectives even after the plugin for that perspective has been uninstalled) around and is set to open on default I could see getting an error like that.  Try removing the Force.com perspective.

1. Open Preferences
2. General->Perspectives
3. Look for Force.com in list of available perspectives
4. Delete it

You might also try clearing out any Force.com projects from your workspace.

And as always, installing a fresh version of eclipse can cure most ills.